# Need some enlightment about how log affects the mean of the data?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, inference, descriptive-statistics, logarithm

So, I have some data regarding the views by videos on youtube. I took the log of the data and compared the mean of both variables. Why did the categories change so much when log was applied (first vector is E(X) for each category and second vector is E(Y) where Y = Log(X)) ?

```
> order(recat$MediaViews, decreasing = TRUE)
 [1]  3  9  1 12 10  7 14  8  5  4 13 16 17  2  6 15 18 11
> order(recat$LogMediaViews, decreasing = TRUE)
 [1]  9  7 12 14  8  1  5  2  4 10  3 13  6 15 18 11 17 16
```

Comment: Could you please explain what these "categories" represent and how they might be related to the data?

Comment: What is the connection between finding $Y_i = \log X_i$ and the geometric mean.
You might want to read about 'arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic means.'

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have some observations (number of views) for some classes of videos (or  videos?) on youtube, and want to rank the classes of videos on mean number of views.  Then you observe that the ranking depends on using number of views or $\log(\text{number of views})$. The reason is that the classes differs also on variance.

To see that, let the number of views of some video be the random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$. Then approximate with a second order Taylor polynomial:
$$
   \log X \approx \log\mu + \frac1{\mu} (X-\mu) -\frac12\frac1{\mu^2}(X-\mu)^2
$$
On taking expectations we get
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
  \E \log X \approx \log\mu -  \frac12\frac1{\mu^2} \sigma^2
$$
So, the classes of videos with higher variance will tend to rank lower based on geometric means than on arithmetic means.

Now, you can check with your data if this is what you see. You can make a third ranking based on the approximation above, and see if that is close to the ranking based on geometric means.